# Sphinx real-time индекс поиск по части слова

Tags: sphinx

Я создал индекс:

```
index berni_filter2
{
    rt_mem_limit    = 512M
    type            = rt
    path            = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/berni_filter

    rt_attr_uint    = product_id
    rt_attr_uint    = store_id
    rt_field        = product_name
    rt_attr_json    = attributes

    prefix_fields   = product_name
    expand_keywords = 1
    min_infix_len   = 2
    dict            = keywords
}
```

Пробую найти товар по имени через SphinxQL:

```
SELECT product_id FROM berni_filter2 WHERE store_id = 0 AND MATCH ('@product_name mothercare')
```

Запрос работает хорошо, но я также хочу, чтобы при поиске "mother" находились товары, содержащие "mothercare". Пробовал:

```
SELECT product_id FROM berni_filter2 WHERE store_id = 0 AND MATCH ('@product_name mother')
SELECT product_id FROM berni_filter2 WHERE store_id = 0 AND MATCH ('@product_name mother*')
SELECT product_id FROM berni_filter2 WHERE store_id = 0 AND MATCH ('@product_name *mother*')
```

Так же менял min_infix_len на min_prefix_len. Ничего не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Моей ошибкой было то, что я не удалял индекс с диска после изменения конфига. Рабочий финальный конфиг:

```
index berni_filter
{
    rt_mem_limit    = 512M
    type            = rt
    path            = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/berni_filter

    rt_attr_uint    = product_id
    rt_attr_uint    = store_id
    rt_field        = product_name
    rt_attr_json    = attributes

    index_exact_words = 1
    expand_keywords   = 1
    min_prefix_len    = 3
    min_word_len      = 2

    morphology        = stem_enru
    dict              = keywords
}
```